# sqoop export to SQL server - with where clause

Tags: export, parameter-passing, where-clause, sqoop, partition

I have partition table. I only want to export partition for today. Is there a way you can pass query with variable in export command ?

Comment: Can you use view?

Comment: You mean create a dynamic view to point to directory for today?

Comment: That will make it easy, am I right?

Comment: I think so . I am going to try Thanks for idea

Comment: So view really does not have directory. So it is not going to work